# Escape white space in column name in Hive

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hive, odbc

I want to write a script to query data from Hive using ODBC. However, the column that I have to make a condition on happen to have a white space in it. As a result, it returned only column names but no result. So, I'd like to know how I can escape the white space in column name, "item id", so that I can get the result I desire returned.

Here is the example of code I used.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

query = "SELECT * FROM tableA " \
    "WHERE 'item id' RLIKE 'AB001.*' LIMIT 2 "

with pyodbc.connect("DSN=HIVE_ODBC", autocommit=True) as conn: 
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

df
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: not familair with HIVE but can you hold the column in square brackets? i.e `[item id]`

Comment: @ Datanovice Thank you for your reply but unfortunately it caused this error: `('42000', "[42000] [Hortonworks][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM tableA " \
 "WHERE `item id` RLIKE 'AB001.*' LIMIT 2 "
```

e.i., instead single-quote use `.